# SQLite bulk data execution

Tags: sqlite

It was taking 72 minutes to execute the 55000 lines of insert statments ..I do have my Schema already built in Sqlite..Please help me to make it quick

```
public static void ExecuteSqlite()
    {
        var strConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = C:\\SMS\\SMS.Database\\SQLiteDatabase\\ESMS.db; Version = 3");
        string strCommand = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\SMS\SMS.Database\SqliteFile\file.txt");
        using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(strConnection))
        {
            db.Open();
            var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            using (SQLiteCommand objCommand = db.CreateCommand())
            {
                using (var transaction = db.BeginTransaction())
                {

                        objCommand.CommandText = strCommand;
                        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
```

Comment: How can "38 seconds" be "even higher" than "never ending"? When you say "lines of bulk data", do you mean 55.000 insert statements? Please note that before the commands can be executed they have to be compiled by the SQLite engine, compiling 55.000 statements is likely to take a lot of time. How much time does it take if you execute the statements using the command line client?

Comment: yeah those are insert statments and it is not executing 55000 lines of code ," i  was taking more than an hour if i use command promt or with out using  Begin transaction "..if i use this BeginTransaction its not even executing ..it was struck for 55000 lines it was working only when my lines of data is less than 25000

Comment: Do you have any indexes, triggers, or constraints?

Comment: I have Constraints but , my schema was already built in sqlite ...I want to insert that data into tables ..It was taking 72 minuets to execute my 55000 lines of code

Comment: Maybe it would help not having multiple statements in one command object.

Comment: No its having whole file in command object

Comment: you can see my code above  ..only one table in the whole data have 19MB of insert lines and it is taking 68min for execution